# Function to calculate "time until" instead of "time ago"

Tags: php, date

I have a function that shows how long ago something.

But now I want to convert to a function that shows how many days are left to go. I have the following code:

```
function ago($eventTime)
{
    $totaldelay = time() - strtotime($eventTime);
    if($totaldelay <= 0)
    {
        return 'Nu';
    }
    else
    {
        if($days=floor($totaldelay/86400))
        {
            $totaldelay = $totaldelay % 86400;
            return $days.' dagen geleden';
        }
        if($hours=floor($totaldelay/3600))
        {
            $totaldelay = $totaldelay % 3600;
            return $hours.' uur geleden';
        }
        if($minutes=floor($totaldelay/60))
        {
            $totaldelay = $totaldelay % 60;
            return $minutes.' minuten geleden ';
        }
        if($seconds=floor($totaldelay/1))
        {
            $totaldelay = $totaldelay % 1;
            return $seconds.' seconden geleden';
        }
    }
}
```

You know how this feature can create a function that allows you to see how many days still to go, instead of ago?

Comment: By reversing the math: `$totaldelay = strtotime($eventTime) - time();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is (what I like to call) a very simple "math & time" issue.
Change `$totaldelay` to `strtotime($eventTime) - time();  //just reverse them, no big deal`.
If you do the math, you will understand why places of`srtotime($eventTime)` & `time()` are changed.